"Life really is short"
I found this sentence in one of my student's notebook.

Life really is short.

And Class teacher also mark that answer as correct. Just wanted to know which one is correct and should use.

Life really is short.
Life is really short.

As always! Thank you so much.

Both are correct and mean the same.

"Is really short" is explaining how short/long, "life really is short" is contrasting with "life isn't short". So there's not really a difference in meaning but they'd be used in different circumstances. There are a lot of existing questions on adverb placement which will cover this in much more detail.

Thanks a lot got it.

@StuartF - I agree that your interpretation that 'life really is short' could be meant to contrast with 'life isn't short', but I don't think that is the only possible meaning.

Really, life is short and Life is short, really are also perfectly valid. But arguably those both feature traditional "whole sentence adverbs* that emphasis the truth of the assertion as a whole,

They have different meanings. The first means "It is true that life is short", the second "Life is very short".

[correction: The class teacher also marked etc. //and should be used, with a d]

I was sure when writing this question that I am in the right hands. Examples are really helpful.

"marked that answer as correct" - what was the question? Both of these are correct, as has been said. To choose between them you would need context. A question simply asking which is right has no correct answer.

@timchessish, as explained, "both are correct". How to mark as correct? any suggestion would be deeply appreciated?

What do you mean by “correct”?  Both are valid English utterances in terms of their syntax. But whether they correctly convey any particular meaning depends on which meaning(s) one intends. That’s what @timchessish is saying.

Positive @PaulTanenbaum. In Student's notebook. This is the only sentence which concerned me.  would you share example of both situation?

See @WeatherVane’s comment. And consider that when the two versions are spoken, it is often with different stress. Life really is short vice Life is really short. The former means that the statement Life is short is indeed true. The latter means that life is not only somewhat short, but extremely brief.


Life really is short.
Life is really short.

Sentences number 1 and 2 are both grammatically correct.
The difference is in the placement of the adverb - really. This difference can impact the meaning of a given sentence, albeit very slightly. For instance, sentence number 1 emphasizes the reality of life being short, while sentence number two focuses more on the shortness itself.
Let's explore some similar nuances with other phrases, focusing on the impact of adverb placement:

I completely understand your frustration.
I understand your frustration completely.

In sentence number 1, the emphasis is on the speaker's thorough comprehension.  They are conveying a deep level of understanding.
In sentence number 2, the emphasis shifts to the extent or totality of the frustration itself.  The speaker acknowledges the frustration's intensity.

Both are correct English utterances in terms of their syntax.
So there's not really a difference in meaning but they'd be used in different circumstances.

There are a lot of existing questions on adverb placement which will
cover this in much more detail. But arguably those both feature
traditional "whole sentence adverbs* that emphasis the truth of the
assertion as a whole.

So in short.
They have different meanings. The first means "It is true that life is short", the second "Life is very short" whether they correctly convey any particular meaning depends on which meaning(s) one intends.
